# Absolute path to an application executable in OS X

Tags: macos, mac, windows

I know where to find the executable file path to an app in Windows. For instance, Adobe Reader:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe`

I need to give the path in a OS X because Excel is asking me for the path. 
What should I write?
Will Preview work?

Comment: I know dropping the app icon to a Terminal will show some path, but I need FULL path :)

Comment: What do you mean by "some path"?

Comment: /Applications/Preview.app  but this does not work. Maybe I need to put "~"

Comment: Nop. Not working ... I'll ask app developer better :P

Comment: Dropping the icon into Terminal.app has always given me the full, absolute, path…What is the app your using called? And what is it doing?

Comment: But this *is* the path of the app. Or do you want the path of the executable in the bundle? /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview

Comment: I guess path of executable, like in windows will work and... I will use Acrobat Reader...gonna check it out

Comment: In my opinion, it is impossible to understand what you want from the title and the question. Please tell us what your specific use case is. *"another app is asking me"* does not tell us what it needs exactly. If we knew for what purpose the app (which App?) is asking for some path we could help you better.

Comment: Ok. I've got an Excel sheet that takes info from a PDF file. To get info, I need to tell where's my Acrobat Reader. There's a default path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe). But I'm using Mac, so I need to change that

Comment: Is Excel popping up a dialog box asking for the path? In what part of the Excel interface are you entering this path information?

Comment: I agree with @oarfish, in Win you may have to launch .exe file to start an app, but in Mac you can just start will .app bundle. You have to tell us what you are trying to achieve, and why. There might be a simpler solution.

Comment: *takes info from a PDF file* – What does that even mean? Screenshots or detailed description might help.

Comment: Can you please add some details about your excel sheet, any excel macro involved and how all interacts? Screenshots may also help in understanding your problem better

Comment: Open this question.

Comment: @Goldname, This question has been closed for almost four years and is not going to be reopened just because you make a comment to open the question.

Comment: @user3439894 Then you may as well delete your answer

Comment: @Goldname, Why should I delete my answer?

Comment: @user3439894 It's a closed question. The point is to prevent people from answering it and consulting it.

Comment: @Goldname, Not sure where you get, or why you think, "and consulting it" has anything to do with it being closed. My answer was posted before it was closed and actually does answer how to get the fully qualified pathname of an app's executable, which certainly is pertinent the question.

Comment: @user3439894 You don't seem to understand what the point of closing a question is. It's a bad question, people shouldn't answer it, and people shouldn't read it. Otherwise, there's no point at all to closing a question. If you agree with that then you should delete your answer, since answers to closed questions are useless.

Comment: @Goldname, You should probably take a look at: [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: @user3439894 It appears you are one of those people who just think in terms of the rules and not what the purpose of the rules are in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

The absolute path to the Adobe Reader executable is:

```
/Applications/Adobe Reader.app/Contents/MacOS/AdobeReader
```

Note the space in `Adobe Reader` and spaces either need to be escaped with a backslash.

```
/Applications/Adobe\ Reader.app/Contents/MacOS/AdobeReader
```

Or quote the fully qualified pathname, but not both.

```
"/Applications/Adobe Reader.app/Contents/MacOS/AdobeReader"
```

You'll have to test to see which form Excel will work with.

You can view the contents of a application bundle by a ctrl-click (right-click) on the application and select "Show Package Contents", then navigate to the `Contents > MacOS` folder where the applications executable is.

For Preview its: `/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview`

Comment: The first option should be the best (It's where the exec is) but not working yet ... maybe this does not work with OS X :( Thanks anyway

Comment: Actually my Adobe Reader  is called "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC". I wrote /Applications/Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.app/Contents/MacOS/AdobeReader but does not work either. None of the options by changing Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

Comment: @user1206365, Because there as spaces you may have to escape them with a backslash or quote the pathname, but not both.  Have you tried that as well?  Have you tried using Preview?

Comment: No, I haven't yet. But I noticed, as my mac is in spanish, "Applications" is called "Aplicaciones" and "Preview" is called "Vista Previa". Should I change that?

Comment: well, does not work either I put: /Aplicaciones/Vista Previa.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview